# how to make multiplication table in listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to view multiplication table in a list view in android.In the form 1*1=1 till 10.
Here is my code.How can i enter mutiplication table into a list view?

```
public class ListClass extends ListActivity{

TextView listView1;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listadp);

        Intent i1 = getIntent();  
        int temp = i1.getIntExtra("yourNumber",0); 

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text_display, tablas(temp)));

        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long  id) {

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        });
    }

    public String[] tablas(int tablas) {

        String[] res = new String[10];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            res[i - 1] = tablas + " x " + i + " = " + tablas * i;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what is the real problem? Do you want to display it as a multiplication table (multiple columns)? Or, your multiplication "list" isn't working properly?

Answer (score 1):

you need a column and a row if you want to make a multiplication **TABLE**. you can make use of  [Gridlayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) or [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Comment: And then you can place that grid in scrollView

Answer (score -1):

scrollview doesn't work in gridview, its(scroll) by default provided in gridview, or else you will end up messing up the layout. so don't insert scrollview in grid, i mean grid in scrollview.